# Can't request data from API "undefined"in console log

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, get, fetch-api

I try to get some data from a public API but I keep getting "undefined" back in my console log.

here is what I tried so far:

```
const api_url = 'https://wger.de/api/v2/exercise/?format=json&page=29';

async function getExercises() {
    const response = await fetch(api_url);
    const data = await response.json();
    console.log(data.name);

}
getExercises();
```

Do you see what I am doing wrong?

Comment: `name` isn't a property in the data returned, its a property in the objects stored at the `results` array

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are trying to access a property that doesn't exsit.
If you change your code to

```
const api_url = 'https://wger.de/api/v2/exercise/?format=json&page=29';

async function getExercises() {
    const response = await fetch(api_url);
    const data = await response.json();
    console.log(data);

}
getExercises();
```

You will find that the returned response doesn't contain a name property inside it.

What you want to do to get the first name of that array of objects.

```
const api_url= 'https://wger.de/api/v2/exercise/?format=json&page=29';

            async function getExercises(){
                const response = await fetch(api_url);
                const data = await response.json();
                console.log(data.results[0].name); // <- results is an array and each item in that array has a name property inside it.

            }
            getExercises();
```

and to get all the names, you can do

```
const api_url= 'https://wger.de/api/v2/exercise/?format=json&page=29';

            async function getExercises(){
                const response = await fetch(api_url);
                const data = await response.json();
                data.results.forEach( item => console.log(item.name))

            }
            getExercises();
```

Answer (score 2):

You can debug and see what data handle:
[image]

then you can get name of data like JS Lover anwser

```
console.log(data.results[0].name);
```